Elastic Search Terms Aggregation query doesn't return all the buckets
I'm trying to return all the serials that are consumed in different boards using following query.
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "currentDatetime": {
            "gte": "2024-04-13T01:00:00.000Z",
            "lte": "2024-04-16T01:00:00.000Z"
          }
        }
      },
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "headers.Type": "GOOD"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "units": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "metrics.serial",
        "size": 500
      },
      "aggs": {
        "board": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "headers.board",
            "size": 3
          }
        },
        "min_2_buckets_selector": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "count": "board._bucket_count"
            },
            "script": {
              "inline": "params.count >= 2"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

But it doesn't return all serials, I know there is one particular serial is consumed in two different boards.
When I add a other match filter and pass the serial, then it returns all right, But I'm trying to get all the serials based on time.

All the fields are in keyword
Searched across all the shards /_search?preference=_shards:0,1,2


Do you get correct results if you don't specify preference? Could you show some sample data you are having issues with that we could reproduce the issue locally?

@imotov no it doesn't return corrected result, with or without preferences.

Sorry cannot help you based on the information provided.
